# Are GIT Bash command "git remote prune origin" and Git-Extensions popup command "Fetch and prune" equal?

Tags: git, git-extensions

In my company, management is using GIT Bash while I am using Git-Extensions.

According to a procedure, I need to launch the GIT Bash command `git remote prune origin`.

In Git-Extensions, there is a popup, called "Fetch and prune", as you can see here:
[image]

Can anybody confirm whether those two actions are the same? In case not, what are the differences?

Is there any way to know the link between any Git-Extensions command and its GIT Bash equivalent?

Comment: As described in the [doc](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-empruneem), they are almost equivalent except that `git reomte prune` does not fetch new refs while `git fetch --prune` does. Different Git GUIs are different dialects. If you are familiar with Git commands, it's natural to know what commands are most probably behind a GUI menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see most of the commands Git Extensions in running in "Git commands" dialog by pressing F12 (Tools > Git Command log):

[image]